# Capture in a lambda expression of anonymous union member

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, unions

As we know [an anonymous union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) is an unnamed union definition that does not simultaneously define any variables. And members of an anonymous union are injected in the enclosing scope. But are there any restrictions on capturing these members in lambda expressions?

In the following example program

```
int main() {
    union {
        int x{0};
        char y[4];
    };

    // error everywhere
    //[=]() { return x; };    
    //[&]() { return x; };

    // ok in GCC only
    [x]() { return x; };
    [&x]() { return x; };

    // ok in all
    [x=x]() { return x; };
    [&x=x]() { return x; };
}
```

all compilers refuse to make implicit capture (both by value `[=]` and by reference `[&]`). E.g. Clang's error is

```
unnamed variable cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda expression
```

As to explicit capture (both by value `[x]` and by reference `[&x]`), here compilers diverge. MSVC prints the same error:

```
error C3492: 'x': you cannot capture a member of an anonymous union
```

The error from Clang changes and becomes less clear:

```
'x' in capture list does not name a variable
```

And GCC permits explicit capture without any warning. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ghq66rjfW

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Added what I usually do (needed until C++20) to capture structured bindings since it helps here too. Perhaps there's a relation to this problem?

Comment: _As we know an anonymous union is an unnamed union definition that does not simultaneously define any variables_ It is not a good idea to blindly copy-paste every nonsense from cppreference. Anonymous unions seem to match the (somewhat vague) definition of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.pre#def:variable

Comment: @LanguageLawyer not sure what you mean. but cppreference is correct here, it just says how to write such construct. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions

Comment: @LanguageLawyer the full quote "An anonymous union is an unnamed union definition that does not simultaneously define any variables (including objects of the union type, references, or pointers to the union)."

Comment: @appleapple ok, it just sounds that cppreference is saying `union { int x{0}; char y[4]; };` does not introduce a variable

Comment: @appleapple anyway, cppreference is not accurate since `union { int x{0}; char y[4]; };` defines a variable, an unnamed one

Comment: @LanguageLawyer it depend on how you interpret "simultaneously define". imo it's pretty clear what cppreference and OP means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The defect report and resolution of [CWG 1612](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1612.html) means that it is not allowed to capture any member of an anonymous union, neither by copy or reference, neither implicitly nor explicitly.

See e.g. [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.sentence-5) and [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.capture#12.sentence-4) in the post-C++20 draft N4868:

> [...] A member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

> [...] A bit-field or a member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by reference.

Comment: It's interesting that clang still allows capturing it by reference if it's named: `[&x=x] { return x; };`

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's not actually capturing `x` as in the member of the anonymous union. It instead captures an imagined variable of reference type which is initialized by the expression `x`.

Comment: Very true that.